# file_get_contents() PHP

Tags: php, encoding

Why have I got trouble with charset on echo?

```
$url = "http://ru.wikipedia.org";
$site=file_get_contents($url);
echo $site;
```

Comment: What character encoding do you use on your page?

Comment: Apparently you’re using a different character encoding for you output than Wikipedia uses for their output (they use UTF-8).

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>




<?php

$url = "http://ru.wikipedia.org";
$site=file_get_contents($url);
echo $site;

?>

</html>

Comment: The character encoding information inside the HTML document is only used when there is no such information in the HTTP header. So better declare the character encoding properly in HTTP than in the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting `header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');` at the start of your file

Comment: I did it! but I have got this trouble again.
screenshot here: http://img510.imageshack.us/img510/5028/123mk.gif

Comment: When I write into html file <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  it does not work too

Comment: Sorry, it's `header()`, not `headers()`

Comment: oh!Sorry! It's my inattention!