# How to deal with special chars in php

Tags: php, encoding

I load a UTF-8 encoded json file using php like this:

```
$string = file_get_contents("_locales/de/messages.json");
```

When I echo `$string` I get chars like

```
delete_context":{ "message": "LÃ¶schen" }
```

where it should be *Löschen*.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Are you setting the encoding on the output page? May be useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487477/get-file-contents-php

Comment: I have a php file without any html for now, header() does not work, I get a headers already sent error

Comment: You could try htmlentities($string) but It should work only in web page.

Comment: regardless of whether its on a webpage or a terminal, is the browser or the terminal encoding set to UTF-8 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible resolution:
[php: file_get_contents encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713293/php-file-get-contents-encoding-problem-solved)

Comment: +1 this is a possible reason/solution.  It could also be that the OP needs to set the encoding for a page he is outputting on.